# Team development with Worklight and GitHub

Tags: github, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working with a small development team where we are working together on a Worklight V6 Project, where we are using GitHub as our repository.  Is there any docs on what artifacts we should be pushing/pulling for a Worklight project with GitHub?  Thanks!

JT

Comment: You might be interested to know I am maintaining a `.gitignore` template for Worklight projects. See [here](https://github.com/andrewferrier/worklight-gitignore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, the fist place to look is [the infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_integrating_with_source_contro.html?resultof=%22source%22%20%22sourc%22%20%22code%22%20%22control%22%20).  In addition, there are a couple of .jazzignore files that get populated in the project tree, and you should be able to add everything in those into your .gitignore.

I have a somewhat old blog post about using Subversion with Worklight [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/using_source_code_management_with_worklight_subversion?lang=en)  Some details will be different with Worklight V6 and git, but it should give you some background

Comment: duh to me, I was searching on github instead of source control.  Thanks!!